# tf.data.Dataset.from_generator save additional data from Python generator

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I would like save additional data (date, file name etc.), which I don't use for training but will need it later to identify my predictions. This data is generated together with features and target by python generator:

```
def gen():
  ...
  yield X, y, additional_data

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen)
```

Should I pack these values into a dataset or is there a more sophisticated method?

Comment: what is this additional data, why not `xy_data = tf.data(gen), addi_data = tf.data(add_gen))`

Comment: @Innat In my case it is a date and location. It can be a valid solution if two generators produce identical data.

Comment: Can you add what have you tried,1. dummy data, 2. data loader, 3. model, ... etc. It's okay if the code breaks. Doing so, it would be clear what is your end goal.